# binutils make error for readelf

Tags: linux, makefile, binutils

When I run `make binutils/readelf` I get the following error:

```
In file included from readelf.c:43:0:
sysdep.h:23:25: fatal error: alloca-conf.h: No such file or directory
 #include "alloca-conf.h"
```

What dependency am I missing? How do I just build and compile readelf without making the rest of binutils?

Comment: Since `#include "alloca-conf.h"` uses the quotation-mark form of `#include`, I would expect that it is part of the binutils distribution.  Have you run `find <src_root> | grep "alloca-conf"` to see if any similarly named files exist...which might need to be processed into the missing header by a configuration step you're skipping?

Comment: I'm not sure that your goal (building a single binary) is going to be possible without a lot of work.  There are many inter-dependencies within binutils, and teasing those apart is going to be tricky if not impossible. I'm also not sure it's worth it from a time savings perspective: compiling all of binutils (starting with `./configure`) takes approximately 40 seconds on my not-very-powerful laptop (with `make -j4`). You could have recompiled the entire project from scratch over 300 times since asking your question four hours ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What has actually happened is that you do not have a `Makefile` or at least not one defining `binutils/readelf` target. But since there is a `binutils/readelf.c` file, make still ran and tried to compile and link `binutils/readelf` using its implicit pattern rules... and failed because this source file cannot be built without corresponding configuration.

This is just to add a bit more detail. Long story short, run `./configure` and `make` as suggested in the comments and collect your resulting `readelf`. Much easier then trying to isolate a solitary item build out of autotools based project. You add `-I` to `CFLAGS` to find `alloca-conf.h`, you'll just run into another problem like that.